# software to scan UPC codes from images

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Is there a server/software that can take an image in and scan it for barcodes (UPC or otherwise) and return the number encoded in the barcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Zxing project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and [online decoder](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx)

Comment: Looked good, but I tried the online decoder with several images that i got from a google search of "barcode" as well as one I took myself of a product on my desk and it was not able to read any of them... (e.g. http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Barcode-EAN13-Bulgaria.jpg) 
Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I was able to get http://www.aemmp.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/barcode1.jpg to work, but this seems rather difficult to get it to read barcodes. If it can't even do some that are clear off the web, what hope is there going to be for user taken photograhps of barcodes?

Comment: We successfully use this library in our Android and IPhone applications.
Where do you plan to use this?

Comment: It just needs to sit on a server and take user taken photos and spit back the barcode. (can't really say beyond that)

Comment: Scan and recognize barcode by one photo is no easy. For example Android library uses camera to find right position and focus. My suggestion to do this on client side.